# Task cancel in calling between Web API endpoints

Tags: c#, sockets, iis, httpclient, webapi

I am getting  task was cancel error calling between two Web API endpoints. The error is occurring intermittently. I have used a single `HttpClient` in my app to avoid socket exhaustion. We are getting continuous requests from web hook since our application is a chat bot.

Could increasing worker thread or queue length on IIS work? (just a wild guess) Or do you have any other suggestions to resolve?

```
private static HttpClient _ProcessBotHttpClient = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(apiRequest.Method), apiRequest.Url);

if (apiRequest.Method != "GET")
{
    request.Content = new StringContent(apiRequest.Data);
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
}
     
_ProcessBotHttpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);

await _ProcessBotHttpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: Please check your IIS logs and provide us with detailed error information.

Comment: `TaskCancelledException` highly likely tells about request timeout, try to wrap `SendAsync` with try/catch and log exception string representation. Just the message will tell about timeout, afaik.

Comment: Since you have set the timeout to 2 minutes, you can try increasing the timeout further to see if that resolves the intermittent issue. Also, wrap the call to SendAsync in a try-catch block and log any exceptions that may occur. This may help identify the specific exception that caused the task to be cancelled.